# XSLT: Copy two files into one common structure

Tags: xslt, ssis, data-profiling

I try to merge result of SSIS Data Profiler Task for several tables into one XML for inspection of the results within one single file inside "Data Profiler Viewer". The whole problem shrinks to the stronly simplified XML-trasformation here:

File 1 (test_1.xml):

```
<a xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/DataDebugger/">
   <b id="1"/>
   <c>
      <2: any other XML-structure to come here/>
   </c>
</a>
```

File 2 (test_2.xml):

```
<a xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/DataDebugger/">
   <b id="1"/>
   <c>
      <1: any other XML-structure to come here/>
   </c>
</a>
```

(Element b is always exacly the same)

Expected result:

```
<a xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/DataDebugger/">
   <b id="1"/>
   <c>
      <1: any other XML-structure to come here/>
      <2: any other XML-structure to come here/>
   </c>
</a>
```

Any help is stronly recommended! I will provide the solution to the original problem here.

Comment: What XSLT version can you use?

Comment: @zx485: I can use, whatever fits the problem best.

Answer (score 0):

Another try:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/DataDebugger/"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"/>

    <xsl:template match="t:c">
        <xsl:element name="c" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/DataDebugger/">
        <xsl:copy-of select="*" />
        <xsl:copy-of select="document('test_2.xml')//t:c/node() " />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

checked with xalan (set classpath in environment)

```
java org.apache.xalan.xslt.Process -IN test1_1.xml -XSL test1.xslt -OUT test1_12.xml
```

and saxon (Change skript to Version = "1.1")

```
java -jar saxon-9.1.0.8j.jar -s:test_1.xml -xsl:test_1.xslt -o:test_12.xml
```